# A puzzling probability question-Clarification needed

Tags: probability

I have been looking the following claim

$$\Pr(\text{sun will rise tomorrow}\mid  \text{sun has risen for } n \text{ days}).$$

As $n\to\infty$, this probability approaches one. This seems intuitive in this context i.e., as you observe more sun rise clearly you bet high on next rise, but if you think about waking up next morning given that you woke up $n$ day, this seems contradictory to me. How is it  possible that probability of waking up a $100$ year-old man is higher than a new born? I am well aware of the fact that I implicitly assume as time passes one is getting closer to not to wake up, but still this seems a clear contradiction. Thanks for any clarification!

Comment: It all accounts to the probability space that you use to model this system, and which events are independent there. For example, if the rise of the sun today is modeled to be independent of the previous observations, then regardless of the historical data the probability will be constant: some $p$ for the rise and $1-p$ for the non-rise.

Comment: To add to what Ilya said, maybe where the dissonance comes from is the fact that you are assuming something about the process--in particular, you are assuming that process has some finite lifespan (i.e. the events are not independent). But I just think the point of the example is to illustrate how previous observations give you information, without thinking too much about other assumptions.